# linking jupyter widget text box to a function plotting a graph

Tags: function, ipywidgets

I am trying to construct a user interface in Jupyter notebook that is able to link one function with a text widget and button widget.

My function creates a plot for the stock price of a given stock from a start date to end date. The functions is as follow

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr

from datetime import datetime


 def company(ticker):
    strt=datetime(2020,1,1)
    end=datetime.now()
    dat=pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker, strt, end)
    return dat['Close'].plot(grid=True)
```

The following command plots apple stock price.

```
company('AAPL')
```

Now i create a text and button widget as follow

```
import ipywidgets as ipw

 box=ipw.Text(
value='Stock handle',
placeholder='Type something',
description='String:',
disabled=False)


 btn=ipw.ToggleButton(
 value=False,
description='Plot',
disabled=False,
button_style='', # 'success', 'info', 'warning', 'danger' or ''
tooltip='Description',
icon='check' # (FontAwesome names without the `fa-` prefix))
```

I tried to link the function company with box as follow:
box.on_submit(company)

When I write AAPL in box it gives me error "TypeError: object of type 'Text' has no len()
"
My goal is to create an interface where i write the name of the stock('AAPL') in the box and click the btn at which point the plot of the stock price will appear.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please can you copy and paste the entire error you receive within a code block? The full stack trace helps to determine the cause.

Answer (score 0):

When you attach a function with `on_submit`, the entire widget gets passed as the argument to the function (not just the text value). So within your `company` function, `ticker` is actually your instance of the `Text` widget. Hence the error, as you cannot call `len` on a widget.

To get the text value of the widget, use `ticker.value`, which you should be able to call `len` on just fine.

```py
def print_it(ticker):
#     print(len(ticker))  # raises TypeError, you're calling len on the Text widget
    print(len(ticker.value))   # will work, as you're accessing the `value` of the widget which is a string
    
t = ipywidgets.Text(continuous_update=False)
t.on_submit(print_it)
t
```

NB. the `on_submit` method is deprecated as of ipywidgets 7.0, much better to create your box using use `box.observe()`, and when you create your box include `continuous_update=False` as a kwarg. With this method, a dictionary of info gets passed to your function, so you need to parse out the new value and print it.

```py
def print_it(ticker):
    print(ticker['new'])   # will work, as you're accessing the string value of the widget
    
t = ipywidgets.Text(continuous_update=False)
t.observe(print_it, names='value')
t
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. However this is not what I am looking for. I do not want to print what is being written in the box. There are several tutorials for that. I want what is written in the box to be used as an input for the function company and resulting output of the function company to be displayed

Comment: Before you were getting a `TypeError` because you couldn't access the text value of your widget, my answer shows you how to get to the text value of your widget, which you should be able to connect to your plotting function.